# How to include provided dependencies with the new Application Run configuration UI in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Where is the "include dependencies with provided scope" check box in the new IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 interface for running a java application? On the earlier version it was present and then suddenly it disappeared.

Comment: Hello, I don't exactly know if this what you're looking for, but maybe it helps. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modify options, Use classpath of module:

[image: classpath of module]

Click on the module, enable the **Include dependencies with "Provided" scope** checkbox:

[image]

[Vote for the corresponding issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256633) to make it easier to find.

Comment: I think this modification is the worst feature of the new version. The older version is far better organized than the new one

Comment: @UnixAgain [already fixed](https://i.imgur.com/AkQo99z.png) in 2020.3.1 preview.

Comment: For anyone who had struggle finding provided scopes  , I found it this way : project structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> there is a list and one of its column's name is "scope" and you can change it to either of these options:  "provided, test, compile, runtime"

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to find it mentioned as above but

I found the option inside the Modify options itself. you can check it.