# How to include provided dependencies with Kotlin configuration UI in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Same question than : [How to include provided dependencies with the new Application Run configuration UI in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135298/how-to-include-provided-dependencies-with-the-new-application-run-configuration) but for Kotlin configurations : is it possible to add provided dependencies to a Kotlin configuration ? I usually can work things out with running Kotlin code from a Java run config, but it's quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin run configurations [do not support it at the moment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-13772).

As a workaround you can use Application run configuration and specify the Kotlin main class that will have `Kt` suffix.

Comment: Thank you, I'll upvote the feature proposal / it's a bit of an ergonomic smell atm.